# base 64 string from Android to SQL not decoding and store in folder using php

Tags: php, android, base64, android-volley

I am sending base64 encode image from Android to SQL server DB but image is not stored in the DB folder. The android step to convert the image into base64 string is mentioned below.

```
    public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
    }
```

After converting image to base64 string using volley i am posting into SQL DB. Then using PHP decode base64 string and save the image path in the DB table. The path is stored but not the image in the folder. What is wrong about it.

PHP code used:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $FoodName = $_POST['FoodName'];
            $FoodLocation = $_POST['FoodLocation'];
    $ShopName = $_POST['ShopName'];
            $Type = $_POST['Type'];
            $image = $_POST['image'];

    require_once('dbConnect.php');

            $sql ="SELECT id FROM Volley ORDER BY id ASC";

    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    $id = 0;

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            $id = $row['id'];
    }

    $path = "images/New folder/$id.jpg";

    $actualpath = "http://ccc.ccc.com/$path";



    $sql = "INSERT INTO Volley (FoodName,FoodLocation,ShopName,Type,image) VALUES ('$FoodName','$FoodLocation','$ShopName','$Type','$actualpath')";


    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
                    file_put_contents('$path',base64_decode($image));
        echo "Successfully posted";
    }else{
        echo "Could not post";

    }
}else{
echo 'error';
}
```

BASE 64 from Android:

```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```

Answer (score 0):

If your base64encoded string has `data:image/jpeg;base64,` appended infront of it, then you need to remove it before `base64_decode`

You can use something like this for it

```
str_replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,","",$image);
```

**UPDATE**

I tried to convert your string [here](http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter) But it seems to be corrupted. The base64 string is not proper.

This might happen, if there are new line characters in the code. So try replacing `\n` or any other white spaces from the string before decoding it. You can use `str_replace("\n", "", $image)` for that as well. Try and let me know

Comment: I edited question with base64 encode string it doesnt append data:image/jpeg;base64, infront of it.

Comment: @user2269164 or if none of the above works, you need to see if you are generating proper base64 string on Android